# Is it safe to backup init.d and rc*.d

Tags: boot, backup, init, runlevel

is it possible to backup `init.d` and `rc*.d` (i.e. `rc3.d`) normally?
just copying and adding `.backup` extension?

I don't want to mess with the symbolic links. 
I'm deactivating unnecessary processes (e.g. bluetooth). but I'd like to back up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest you use your distribution's service config manager to do this, rather than disabling things yourself.

For centos/redhat this would be '`chkconfig`'. If you let us know what distribution you're on, we can probably tell you the best way.

That said, the scripts in those folders are going to be symbolic links or scripts. They are called in the order of their name (alphabetically, numbers first) There shouldn't be any major down side to messing with them yourselves except for the distribution's `chkconfig` not being able to keep track.

Comment: Ok. I'm on Ubuntu. I've heard the name Upstart -- would that be it? I was planning to use "sysv-rc-conf" to do it, but before I changed anything in that I wanted to back up what it was adjusting -- i.e., init.d and the rc*.d's.